# Why does IQueryable implement IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

I understand why `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable exist`, but I'm unclear what benefits I get from `IQueryable` deriving from `IEnumerable`.

One of the downsides I've come across:

- Anyone creating their own `IEnumerable` extension methods can easily accidentally transform an innocent looking `IQueryable` query into an inefficient `IEnumerable` call. For example, using MoreLinq:

  ```
   Users.DistinctBy(u => u.Address).Where(u => u.Age >= 18)
  ```

(This will use `IEnumerable.Where` rather than `IQueryable.Where` unless I have missed an `IQueryable` implementation of the above)

The way that `IQueryable` works, with an internal `Expression` which gets altered by the chained statements, seems quite different to how chained functions are normally expected to work.

I suspect this interface inheritance has some powerful upsides which I am probably not making full use of. What are the benefits of having `IQueryable` implement `IEnumerable` compared to, for example, having an explicit conversion which executes the query?

Comment: Judging by the number of questions on Stack Overflow caused by this API design I'd say you are right.

Comment: this is way too opinion based.

Comment: *and instead have an explicit method call to convert between the two, explicitly triggering the query execution* There is, it's called `AsEnumerable()` :-)

Comment: I'll add that linq (from, where, select...) work with Duck Typing, so they don't really need interfaces. forach too works with Duck Typing, so give him a `GetEnumerator()` (without a IEnumerable) and it would work

Comment: If you want to know why MS made the decision that they did then you'll need to *ask them* rather than asking us to guess at why they may have made the decision that they did, as that's simply not productive, nor is it an objectively answerable question.

Comment: @Servy There are various MS programmers/ex MS programmers here on SO, and often the knowledge is given to these questions :-)

Comment: Have altered the question to be more answerable. I am genuinely curious to know if there are any benefits to this, as I implement generic interfaces myself and might help me design APIs myself better in future.

Comment: @xanatos And yet out of the many thousands of people who have ever been MS programmers, only a handful will have been involved in this decision.  Having questions here that only a handful of people in the entire world can ever answer, and to which the odds of them ever reading it are minuscule, is just not productive for everyone here.

Comment: @MichaelParker After your edit the question is even more opinion based/subjective than before.

Comment: Could you help me understand why this is opinion based now? I'm not asking for whether people are in favour of IQueryable implementing IEnumerable - i'm asking for the benefits of it doing so. That should be quite possible to answer factually.

Comment: My question would be, why is DistinctBy not consuming and returning an IQueryable<T>?

Comment: Seems if you add `public static class MyExtensions {
 public static IQueryable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> items, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> property)
 {
  return items.GroupBy(property).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
 }
}` then your problem goes away.

Answer (score 5):

(I **do** think that it was stupid to have `IQueryable` inherit from `IEnumerable`)... But!

**it just works**

this is the [leitmotif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitmotif) of collections in .NET . There is no safety net if you want to do a `Contains` on a `List<>` collection (doing a O(n) operation). There is no safety net if you re-execute the same query multiple times because you don't know the difference between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` (and note that even `IEnumerable` doesn't guarantee the caching of results :-) ).

Thanks to this inheritance, all the methods that accept an `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` accept a `IQueryable`/`IQueryable<T>`/`IOrderedQueryable<T>`

**it just works**

Legions of VB programmers where happy with the Variant data type... Legions of .NET programmers will be happy with slow queries :-)

As always, there is space for excellency and there is space for sloppy programming. There is space for anyone :-)

I'll add that the example you gave is from an external library, with a description that says `LINQ to Objects is missing a few desirable features.`
(and note that `DistinctBy` can be "simulated" with `GroupBy` + `Select(First())`, so it could be built IQueryable-compatible). So you are using a hammer like a screw and you complain that it isn't the right instrument :-)

The extension methods given by Microsoft that don't produce collections are normally `IQueryable`-safe (except with `Expression` vs `Func`)

Just out of curiousity, the official reason of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable) is:

> The IQueryable interface inherits the IEnumerable interface so that if it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated. Enumeration causes the expression tree associated with an IQueryable object to be executed.

[And](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This interface inherits the IEnumerable<T> interface so that if it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated. Enumeration forces the expression tree associated with an IQueryable<T> object to be executed. Queries that do not return enumerable results are executed when the Execute<TResult>(Expression) method is called.

Sadly (at least for me), this isn't a reason good enough, because they could have

- Simply let the `AsEnumerable()` do the work in an explicit way

or

- Put in the `IQueryable` (and related) interfaces a method `GetEnumerator()`, because `foreach` uses duck typing and it would have been happy.

For example:

```
public interface IMyEnumerabe<T>
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}

IMyEnumerabe<int> myenumerable = null;

foreach (int el in myenumerable)
{
    // Compiles (and in this cases crashes with a NullReferenceException :-) )
}
```